# Action bar buttons showing only in overflow (not extending ActionBarActivity)

Tags: android-actionbar

I can only find solutions to this for the case of using the support library. 
Facts:

1. build.gradle:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
   }
   ```
2. menu_main.xml:

   ```xml
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"                
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <item
       android:id="@+id/ab_main_share"
       android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
       android:title="Share"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_input_antenna_black_24dp"
       android:actionProviderClass=
           "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />

   <item
       android:id="@+id/ab_main_delete"
       android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
       android:title="Delete"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp" />

   <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"    android:title="@string/action_settings"
       android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />

   </menu>
   ```
3. MainActivity.java:

   ```java
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

   ...

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate menu resource file.
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

       /** Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is share */
       mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.ab_main_share).getActionProvider();

       /** Setting a share intent */
       mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

       return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
   ```

And the result is that the actions appear in the overflow. I tried also to put just one action, but I get the same result. So it's not a problem of not having room in the action bar (and the name of the app or the application icon is not so wide).

Am I missing something? I did these thing before with the support library and had no problems, but this app is minSdkVersion 17, so there's no reason to use it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! The problem was in the Manifest. I had this in the activity declaration:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"
```

Removed it and now I can see the action buttons in the action bar.