# action buttons only show in overflow in navigationmaterialdrawer library

Tags: android, android-actionbar, themes, material-design

I use this library ([NavigationMaterialDrawer](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer))  for implementing drawer and managing accounts but when i add some action buttons to it,the action buttons only show in overflow menu even if considering always for showAsAction

[image]

as you see i click on overflow menu and i see this. but i want to see search icon in action bar

this is my code

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

init method:

```
public void init(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_drawer,null);
    setDrawerHeaderCustom(view);


    this.addSection(newSection("Section 1", new FragmentIndex()));
    this.addSection(newSection("Section 2",new FragmentIndex()));
    this.addSection(newSection("Section 3", R.drawable.ic_mic_white_24dp,new FragmentButton()).setSectionColor(Color.parseColor("#9c27b0")));
    this.addSection(newSection("Section",R.drawable.ic_hotel_grey600_24dp,new FragmentButton()).setSectionColor(Color.parseColor("#03a9f4")));


    this.addBottomSection(newSection("Bottom Section",R.drawable.ic_settings_black_24dp,new Intent(this,Settings.class)));


getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
setTitle("TestTitle");


}
```

and this is my test_menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:MaterialNavigationDrawer="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
android:title="Search"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
MaterialNavigationDrawer:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

I import library to android studio because i guess for solving this issue i have to rewrite some class or xml but i don't know where. is it right?

**UPDATE**
I use sample of this library([Source](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer/tree/master/MaterialNavigationDrawer)) for test.

maybe it because of my theme!
I read this queston([Action bar buttons showing only in overflow (not extending ActionBarActivity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058882/action-bar-buttons-showing-only-in-overflow-not-extending-actionbaractivity)) and delete theme but the sample code not working without theme.it force closed on a line of library. i move my code to another activity of sample(account light) with another theme and i have the same issue. then i delete theme from this but it force closed too :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:124)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
        at it.neokree.materialnavigationdrawer.MaterialNavigationDrawer.onCreate(MaterialNavigationDrawer.java:361)
```

i want to use theme in future!so i can't delete theme entirely. wich element on theme must changed or deleted?

Comment: try `android:showAsAction="always"` instead of `MaterialNavigationDrawer:showAsAction="always" />`

Comment: I get error if i use this because of appcompat. android studio offer to me use 
MaterialNavigationDrawer:ignore="AppCompatResource" and i use this but problem is not solved yet.

Comment: @frgnvola is mention work in stack? do you get notification?! :D

Comment: Yes, I got the notification :). Try `android:showAsAction="always"` instead, because you are using the support library.

Comment: @frgnvola this is not working for me :) i update my post see bottom of question :)

Comment: Oops, I meant to suggest `app:showAsAction="always"`

Comment: @frgnvola :)) I already use this ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i already mentioned in question problem is with theme!
in MaterialNavigationModule>res>values>themes.xml change parent of styles to

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar
```

instead of

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```